# How to detect if one of some items are clicked in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, onclick

i have a similar list:

```
<a id="item1" class="outofstock">item 1</a>
<a id="item2" class="outofstock">item 2</a>
<a id="item3" class="instock">item 3</a>
<a id="item4" class="instock">item 4</a>
<a id="item5" class="instock">item 5</a>
```

These items are loaded by an ajax request. i want to show an alert when an user click on an "out of stock" item. i alredy tryed this:

```
$('.outofstock').click(function(){
alert("Sorry, this item is out of stock");
});
```

But, only the first "out of stock" item will show the alert. if i click on another one, nothing happen. What should i do to add an alert to each  ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/g4tuC/.

Comment: each ... is the word (take a look at my answer)

Comment: I wonder why it is not working!!! :-o Here it is working. http://jsfiddle.net/g4tuC/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work as your currently have it, if the objects were not being loaded by ajax, as seen in the demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BPCSx/).

However, since the objects are being loaded with AJAX, you may want to replace your **[click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** event with the [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event, as shown below:

```
$('.outofstock').click(function(){
    alert("Sorry, this item is out of stock");
});
```

**should be:**

```
$('.outofstock').live('click',function(){
    alert("Sorry this item is out of stock");
});
```

This will ensure that all elements that fall under that selector will use this event, including any elements that have not yet been created.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.target` to determine which element was clicked.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g4tuC/2/)**

```
$('.outofstock').click(function(e){
   alert("Sorry, " + e.target.id + " is out of stock" + );
});
```

Or if you want to grab the element content

```
$('.outofstock').click(function(e){
   alert("Sorry, " + $(this).html() + " is out of stock");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are loaded by an AJAX request then the normal `click` event handler will not work.  You will need to suplement it with the [live](http://jqapi.com/#p=live) function:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

Try:

```
$('.outofstock').live('click', function(){
    alert("Sorry, " + $(this).text() + " is out of stock");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it respective to each element ;-)

```
$('.outofstock').each(function(){
    live('click', function(){
       alert("Sorry, this item is out of stock");
    });
});
```

And use live because of AJAX...

Answer (score 1):

I often find this method useful in an ajax scenario.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

   if ($(e.target).is('.outofstock')) {
            alert("Sorry, this item is out of stock");
    }
}
```

Even if there is a post back the click event remains bound to the document and not individual items.